# Simplify if-else-statement

Tags: php

Is there any simpler way to write the following code? It will be much bigger than 2 cases, so it will be difficult to handle soon.

```
if ($result == 'yes')
{
    echo 'this text';
}
else if ($result == 'no')
{
    $result = in_string($kairos_array, explode(' ', $input_string));

    if ($result == 'yes')
    {
        echo 'that text';
    }
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php ?

Comment: Use `switch/case` statements. And what exactly will be more than two? Within the `else if ($result=='no')` block? Or additional `else if` statement in the outer if/elseif?

Answer (score 0):

You probably can reorganise your code - create a function and just use `return` when you've found what you need. This way the nesting won't increase and the code will be easy to read.

```
if ($result == 'yes')
{
    return 'this text';
}

$result = in_string($kairos_array, explode(' ', $input_string));
if ($result == 'yes')
{
    return 'that text';
}
```

(note, I've removed check for `$result == 'no'` as it's not needed at all if the value can be only 'yes' or 'no')